# 500 Internal Error when searching specific data in Datatables using Ignited Datatables Codeigniter

Tags: json, ajax, codeigniter, datatable, datatables

I'm using Ignited Datatables in Codeigniter to show data from database. It works fine and the data shows normally. But when I'm searching specific data in datatables (using datatables search box), it shows me an error like this:

> DataTables warning: table id=table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Controller:

```
public function json(){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $this->m_bahan->json();
}
```

Model:

```
function json() {
    $this->datatables->select('*');
    $this->datatables->from('t_bahan');
    return $this->datatables->generate();
}
```

View:

```
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="5%">No</th>
        <th>Nama Bahan Dasar</th>
        <th width="175px"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
table = $('#table').DataTable({
    processing: true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
    serverSide: true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
    order: [[1, 'desc']], //Initial order.
    // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
    ajax: {
        url: "bahan/json",
        type: "POST"
    },
    //Set column definition initialization properties.
    columns: [
        {
            data: 'id_bahan',
            orderable: false,
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
            }
        },
        {data: 'nama_bahan'},
        {
            className: 'center',
            orderable: false,
            defaultContent: '<button class="btn btn-warning fa fa-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"> Ubah</button> <emsp/> <button name="delete" class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash"> Hapus</button>'
        }
    ]
});
```

Debug:
[image]

[image]
But, when I directly visit the `bahan/json` url from the browser, it prints the json result.

What's wrong here?

Comment: A 500 error is most likely a problem querying the data in your model. In your model, try before return: `print_r($this->datatables->generate());die;`  What does it output? check the browser network console, you might see a database error.

Comment: @Vickel You can see in the image above. It's not returning json, but a web page.

Comment: no, it tells you exactly what's wrong: `error undefined index: id_bahan in libraries line 331`. Now you need to find out why index is undefined

Comment: Yes, I know that. Do you know what's wrong here? I use Ignited Datatables library for it.

Comment: check your column definition:  `data: 'id_bahan'`, maybe you are using another column name that is not `id_bahan` in your `t_bahan` table structure

Comment: I'm using ```id_bahan``` and in the ```t_bahan```, there are only two rows (```id_bahan``` and ```nama_bahan```).

Answer (score 0):

Ignited Datatables doesn't reply if you using "*" in your query, please write in spesific tables. $this->datatables->select('id_bahan, nama_bahan');